# Calculating Power of a sign test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-power, sign-test

[image]

I'm really stuck on part (e). I want to calculate the power of the sign test. So to find the power of first test. I let $M$ be the number of observations greater than $4.7$. Now I need to find Power which is $P(M\in R|\theta=9.5)$. But for this what I was thinking is we first have to find

$P(X_i>4.7|\theta=9.5)=1-P(X_i\leq 4.7|\theta=9.5)=1-P(x_i=0)-P(x_i=1)-P(x_i=2)-P(x_i=3)-P(x_i=4)=1-[\dfrac{9.5^0}{0!} e^{-9.5}+..+\dfrac{9.5^4}{4!}e^{-9.5}]=.959737$

This is equal to the probability that any observation is greater than 4.7 under the assumption that's Poisson with $\theta=9.5$

Now let $R$ be the critical region such that $P(M\leq m_1)+P(M\geq m_2)=0.036$  where $M\sim \text{Bin}(7.5,\frac{1}{2})$ since this is a two sided test. But I found $m_1=3$ to make this relationship work.

$P(M=0)+...+P(M=3)={15\choose0}.5^{15}+..+{15\choose 3}.5^{15}=.01757=.018$ or $m_2=12$.

Thus we found that $R=\{M\leq 3 \textrm{ or } M\geq 12\}$. Now to find

$P(M\in R|\theta=9.5)={15\choose 0}(.959737^0)(.040263^{15})+...+{15\choose 3}(.959737^3)(.040263^{12})+{15\choose 12}(.959737^{12})(.040263^3)+{15\choose 13}(.959737^{13})(.040263^2)+..+.959737^{15}=.998$.

This seems very high for the first test. Would this be correct?

Comment: The only thing that I think may make this wrong is my rejection region $R$. But I was thinking that since this is a two sided test then I need to divide the alpha value for the two tails.

Comment: It's Correct :)